# How to store multiple arrays in one query laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, model-view-controller, eloquent

In view file is displayed players for each team in match.

here is code in view:

```
@foreach($match->homeTeam->players as $player)
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">{{$player->id}}</th>
        <td class = "col-md-6" name = "fact[player]" value = "{{$player->id}}">{{$player->name}} {{$player->surname}}</td>
        <td align="center" class= "col-md-2"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="gridCheck"></td>
        <td class = "col-md-2"><input id="minutes" type="integer" class="form-control" name="fact[minutes]"></td>
        <td class = "col-md-2"><input id="goals" type="integer" class="form-control" name="fact[goals]"></td>
   </tr>
@endforeach
```

So i need to store them in Match_facts table.

How to insert all in one query?

Comment: Please embed the code into the Question, rather than an image of the code. This is so we can try to edit it to work and otherwise play around with it to see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Founded solution:

```
$home_team_players=$match->homeTeam->players;
        $away_team_players=$match->awayTeam->players;
        $match_players = $home_team_players->merge($away_team_players);

             foreach ( $match_players as $k => $p  ) {
                    $data[] = [
                        'match_id' => $match->id,
                        'player_id' => $p->id,
                        'minutes' => $request['minutes'][$k],
                        'goals' => $request['goals'][$k]
                    ];
                }
                Match_fact::insert( $data );
                return view('admin.matches.index')->with('success','ADDED SUCCESSFULLY .');
```

Answer (score 0):

Match model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Team;

class Match extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['round', 'league_id', 'home_team_id', 'away_team_id', 'match_date'];

    public function leagues() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\League');
    }

    public function homeTeam() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Team', 'home_team_id');
    }

    public function awayTeam() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Team', 'away_team_id');
    }

}
```

Player model:

```
 <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Player extends Model
{
    public function team() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Team');
    }
}
```

In view addResult i have displayed Match(home_team and away_team)
and players of each team.
So i want to store match facts in table (match_facts) for each player of the team

```
Schema::create('match_facts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->uuid('match_id');
            $table->uuid('player_id');
            $table->integer('minutes')->nullable();
            $table->integer('goals')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```